# C# ReadallLines display in ListBox Not Working

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and have been trying for hours to accomplish this simple task of reading a file into an array and displaying in a listbox.  However, it never seems to read the file and the listbox is blank and I don't get any errors.  What am I missing?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WorldSersisChamps
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\jsommer\Documents\Classes\WorldSersisChamps\WorldSersisChamps\bin\Debug\Sales.txt");


                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    lbTeams.Items.AddRange(lines);
                }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code should works fine. Try *Rebuild* your project once. Also you don't need the `foreach` loop, the `AddRange` is enough here.

Comment: Drop foreach loop. Just one AddRange

Comment: You're using a loop on lines, and in each loop you're adding all the lines. Might want to fix that first. Also, are you sure the file is being read correctly? try setting a break point and inspecting the value of `lines`

Comment: FYI: For each line in the file, your code adds ALL the lines in the File (resulting in lines.length^2 total entries). Lose the foreach loop or change `AddRange(lines)` to `Add(line)`

Comment: Did you wire the load event up?  Use the OnLoad override instead.

Comment: I dropped the loop.  still have issue.

Comment: LarsTech what do you mean by wire up the load event?

Comment: Replace `private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` with `protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)`

Comment: LarsTech that was the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Events have to be subscribed to.  To make your posted code work, you would have had to add `this.Load += Form1_Load;` to your constructor block in order for that load method code to run.